# Prove that $n<2^n$ for every positive integer $n$

Tags: calculus, induction

Prove that $n<2^n$ for every positive integer $n$.

$P(1): 1 < 2^1$

$n+1<2^n+1$ for induction hypothesis

$n+1<2^n+2^n$ I can't undertstand this passage (this is from my teacher's slide)

$n+1<(2)2^n$

$n+1<2^{n+1}$

Comment: By the way, I see that on your own questions, there are no accepted answers. If you see an answer that is best for you and it also works for you, consider going back to your old questions and click on the checkmark below the down arrow (downvote arrow) to accept that answer. Doing so you will get +2 reputation. You might also want to check this [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) page and the [Help Center](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that $n<2^n$ is true.

We need to prove that $n+1<2^{n+1}$ is also true.

This is true because $n<2^n\Rightarrow n+1<2^n+1<2^n+2^n<2^n\times2=2^{n+1}$

($2^n>1$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z^+}$)

Comment: Why $1$ becomes $2^n$?

Comment: This is an assumption. It does not prove anything. It is like saying $2 < 1$ so $2+1<1+1$ proved :/ **Edit:** Ok after your edit, I take that back :)